# dc.js Stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript

I am new in JavaScript and need help in stack bar chart using csv file.
This is what i am doing now but this code is not working.

```
 var chart = dc.barChart("#test");
 d3.csv("Election1.csv", function(error, experiments) {

 var ndx = crossfilter(experiments);
 var all = ndx.groupAll();

 var ProvinceDim=ndx.dimension(function (d){
  return d.Province;
});

var eventsByDate = ProvinceDim.group().reduce(
    function (p, v) {
        p.Chairman Nmae += v.Chairman Nmae;
        p.Colour += v.Colour;

        return p;
    },
    function (p, v) {
        p.Chairman Nmae -= v.Chairman Nmae;
        p.Colour -= v.Colour;

        return p;
    },
    function () {
        return {
            Chairman Nmae: 0,
            Colour: 0,

        };
    }
);
```

I have already created the object for the column in CSV file. i want to show stacked bar chart according to province, colour and chairman name. please help me.